# Splitting based on delimiter and string

Tags: java, split

```
String CompanyData = "{ChargeCompany1Cnt:0,ChargeCompany2Cnt:73,ChargeCompany3Cnt:44,BalanceCompany3Cnt:0,ChargeCompany4Flag:green,BalanceCompany2Flag:green,BalanceCompany1Cnt:0,ChargeCompany3Flag:red,ChargeCompany1Flag:green,BalanceCompany4Flag:green,BalanceCompany1Flag:green,BalanceCompany2Cnt:0,BalanceCompany4Cnt:0,BalanceCompany3Flag:green,ChargeCompany2Flag:red,ChargeCompany4Cnt:6}";
```

CompanyData is my string I am splitting the data like below. There is no issue with this code, but if the order is changed in the string splitting is breaking.
how to split this  string and assign to another string by its name(like splitting based on ChargeCompany1Cnt, ChargeCompany2Cnt). i have used `cut` and `sed` commands in UNIX to do this, right now converting my Shell script into JAVA. So sorry if it's a basic question

```
String ChargeCompany1Cnt=CompanyData.split(,)[0].replace("{","");
String ChargeCompany2Cnt=CompanyData.split(,)[1];
String ChargeCompany3Cnt=CompanyData.split(,)[2];
String BalanceCompany3Cnt=CompanyData.split(,)[3];
String ChargeCompany1Flag=CompanyData.split(,)[8];
```

Basically I need to find String like ChargeCompany2Cnt,ChargeCompany1Flag in CompanyData and print  ChargeCompany2Cnt:73 ChargeCompany1Flag:green

Comment: I guess what you really need as a result, would be a list of Company objects with fields like number, ChargeCnt, ChargeFlag, BalanceCnt, BalanceFlg?

Comment: @Ridcully, Basically i need to find String like ChargeCompany2Cnt,ChargeCompany1Flag in CompanyData and print ChargeCompany2Cnt:73 ChargeCompany1Flag:green

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923544/java-equivelant-to-uix-cut

Comment: Do you really only need to print it? And only in that format? Then Karthik's solution should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Please note if this is JSON object you can parse it easily with ObjectMapper 
of Jacson. you can use the below code for manual parsing

```
    String CompanyData = "{ChargeCompany1Cnt:0,ChargeCompany2Cnt:73,ChargeCompany3Cnt:44,BalanceCompany3Cnt:0,ChargeCompany4Flag:green,BalanceCompany2Flag:green,BalanceCompany1Cnt:0,ChargeCompany3Flag:red,ChargeCompany1Flag:green,BalanceCompany4Flag:green,BalanceCompany1Flag:green,BalanceCompany2Cnt:0,BalanceCompany4Cnt:0,BalanceCompany3Flag:green,ChargeCompany2Flag:red,ChargeCompany4Cnt:6}";
    HashMap<String,String> mymap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for ( String s: CompanyData.split("[?,{}]")) {
        if (!s.equals(""))
        mymap.put(s.split(":")[0],s.split(":")[1]); }

        for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : mymap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey().toString();;
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println( key + " =  " + value );
```

Comment: Calling s.split(":") two times is not very performant. Better do something like `String[] parts = s.split(":"); mymap.put(parts[0], parts[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but perhaps this snippet will point you in the right direction:

```
List<String> companyCount = new ArrayList<>();
String[] companies = CompanyData.substring(1, -1).split(",");
for (String companyCnt : companies) {
    companyCount.add(companyCnt);
}
```

Incidentally, you can probably perform this whole operation without use of cut(1) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you intend to use the variables you could alternatively create a set of key-value pairs instead of explicitly declaring each variable.
Then you could split the names out (i.e. split each element further on `:`) and use them as keys without needing to know which is which.